# Why do I get bound mismatch error wen calling Enum.valueOf() using a wildcard

Tags: java, generics, enums, mismatch, bounded-wildcard

I am trying to call the `Enum<E>` class's static method `valueOf()` but I received a compile error.
Please look at the code snippet below.

```
public void hello(Class<? extends Enum<?>> q){  
    Object o= Enum.valueOf(q,"hello");      
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA complies the following code just fine, but Eclipse gives a compile error:

[image]

Comment: Please check now , I have edited it--that was a typing error.

Comment: Create [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I cannot understand your question.

Comment: Did you put this code in you IDE , and check ? I am getting compile error in the line where I call the .valueOf() method.

Comment: Let me put a screenshot here...

Comment: jason Z: I just added a picture of the error I am getting , next to my question.Please have a look.

Comment: Java 1.7 : I just pasted the same code in IntelliJ and no compile error ; but In eclipse it gives me an error. Is it a bug with Eclipse?

Comment: Just try to run the code in IJ and you will get the same error that eclipse shows at compile time , so this means that the code has some error in it ; which brings us to original question as to why this code is erroneous?

Comment: @StackFlowed The question contains an MCVE if you care to put the method in a class.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know IntelliJ's workings, but I can tell you the reason why it doesn't compile.

The method defined in the class `Enum<T extends Enum<T>>`

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)
```

has a first argument that is the class of a type `T` which is defined by `T extends Enum<T>`. That is, it extends an enumeration type with *the same* generic type as itself.

When you call the method with the first argument as

```
Class<? extends Enum<?>>
```

you are not specifying that the two `?` are in fact the same type, as required. This throws the mismatch error.

What you can do with your method is turn it generic:

```
public static <E extends Enum<?>> void hello(Class<E> q)
```

but as you can imagine, this will still not compile because `?` is not necessarily `E`. So you need to spell it out:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> void hello(Class<E> q)
```

and this will compile.

**Edit: another way to think about it**

You could think of fixing your method signature

```
public void hello(Class<? extends Enum<?>> q)
```

by changing it to

```
public void hello(Class<E extends Enum<E>> q)
```

just to specify that the two wildcards are the same. The concept is right, but the syntax is not legal. You must define what `E` is (either by making your method generic or your class).

Comment: But ONLY an enum class Test1 can extend Enum<Test1>. So ? extends Enum<?> ; will have ? values which will be the same. Which means when you call valueOf() static method , you will pass the variable T such that T will extend Enum<T>.

Comment: @Raj I don't think the compiler can know this during type erasure. The unbounded `?` is replaced with `Object` while `? extends X` is replaced with `X`.